# Chart JS | How to align ticks labels with chart lines?

Tags: canvas, charts, chart.js, html5-canvas

Im trying to align tick labels on the right with green chart lines. Also the problem is that my chart lines will change depending on what user will choose in options. If this is not possible, can I set Label Offset separately for each label? (look code)

I tried to animate it like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2jc13qwx/) but it didn't work either.

Code:

```
scales: {
                            x: {
                                display: true,
                                title: {
                                    display: true,
                                    text: 'WIEK (TYGODNIE)'
                                }
                            },
                            y: {
                                display: true,
                                title: {
                                    display: true,
                                    text: 'WAGA'
                                }
                            },
                            centile: {
                                display: true,
                                position: 'right',
                                ticks: {
                                    callback: function(value, index) {
                                        return centile_labels[index-1];
                                    },
                                    crossAlign: 'near',
                                    labelOffset: -15,
                                },
                                grid: {
                                    display: false,
                                },
                            }
                        },
```

How does it look like:

[my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG7iy.png) (idk how to post image in question sorry)

Comment: You can reposition the ticks in the [axes callbacks](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#callbacks), for instance in 
 `afterTickToLabelConversion`. If you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with some concrete data, you'll get a more precise answer